# Anyway to remove quotes from array itself in python?

Tags: python, arrays

I have an array like this

```
value = ["['A','B','C']" , "['B','A','D']" , "['E','A','C']"]
```

How do I remove those double quotes from each index in the array ?

Comment: You want to *parse* those lists. If you search for that, you should be able to find solutions.

Comment: Take a look at https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval.  
`json.loads` should also do the trick.

Comment: @AshwaniDausodia JSON uses double quotes for strings

Answer (score -1):

```
In [2]: value = ["['A','B','C']" , "['B','A','D']" , "['E','A','C']"]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         

In [3]: import ast                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            

In [4]: value = [ast.literal_eval(L) for L in value]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          

In [5]: value                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
Out[5]: [['A', 'B', 'C'], ['B', 'A', 'D'], ['E', 'A', 'C']]
```